# Difficulty in deploying android application in vs2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

Using Visual Studio 2015
Trying to deploy simple hello world..! application on emulator. Emulator starts successfully. but while deploying app on emulator -> starts build and then throws error "Process system is not responding" Please Help me out of this. I have done xamarin installation manually. (jdk-8u102-windows-i‌​586 using)

emulator I am using attached file(2)
Error I am getting attached file (1)

Comment: add more information for understand better the problem that you have. Print screen help

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0xqp4.png
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XX3MO.png Plz find error and emulator i used attached file here. I am stucked.... new to this platform... not getting idea how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Install the xamarin android player emulator don't use the generic. And try is resolve let me know

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/

Comment: Installed XAP .Trying to start -> Nexus 4 (Marshmallow) But getting Error ::  OpenGL Error. "Failed to initialise OpenGL renderer process".

Comment: Using Windows 7 AND Mobile Intel(R) 45 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)
Has installed on my PC

Comment: please find attached file below in answer section

Comment: @Amruta In my answer I say to you that install the Xamarin Android Player. Use this not the generic. Install first this.

Comment: I have installed as per link -> https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/

Answer (score 0):

Marcos jose as you mentioned error file attached here
[Error print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFlQ9.png)